# how to parse through a complex array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a $photo_array and I want to get a specific URL.

Here is my PHP.. I'm pretty sure that I'm not doing this right:

```
$photo_array = $user_photos->asArray(); 

foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{
    $url = $photo_array["data"]->$key->images->["0"]->source;
    echo $url."<br>";
}
```

Here is a copy of my array... see arrows to see the value I want to get.
and the foreach must be applied to the first [0] ... so I only want 1 URL in each of the key

```
Array
(
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object         <<<<<  FOREACH  applies to this key HERE
            (
                [id] => 123
                [created_time] => 2013-04-21T22:22:33+0000
                [from] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 123
                        [name] => name
                    )

                [height] => 479
                [icon] => https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEhvv3RhPvjk.gif
                [images] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [height] => 1365
  ***THIS IS WHAT I WANT >>>>>  [source] => https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t31.0-8/9034014_10151555782563_1289220490_o.jpg
                                [width] => 2048
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [height] => 960
                                [source] => https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t31.0-8/p960x960/9032201_101513582563_1480490_o.jpg
                                [width] => 1440
                            )

                        [2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [height] => 720
                                [source] => https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t31.0-8/p720x720/903401_101513782563_148970_o.jpg
                                [width] => 1080
                            )

                    )

                [link] => https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151351263&set=a.41902562.210698.6182562&type=1
                [updated_time] => 2014-11-24T22:43:04+0000
                [width] => 720
```

How can I do that... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($photo_array['data'] as $photo) {
    // iterate all images:
    foreach ($photo->images as $image) {
        echo $image->source;
    }

    // or just the first one:
    echo $photo->images[0]->source;
}
```

Comment: He only wants one image url. `"foreach must be applied to the first [0] ... so I only want 1 URL in each of the key"`

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing it wrong. `data` is an `array`, not an `object`. This should work:

```
$url = $photo_array["data"][$key]->images['0']->source;
```

<sup>*The same thing applies for the `images`. It's an `array` and not an `object`.*</sup>

---

- When accessing an array, you'd apply the index (i.e. `[0]`) directly to the array name.
- While accessing an object, you'd access the key (index) via `->`.